# Yandex mapkit swift cocopoads

Tags: ios, swift, yandex-maps-api

Возникла необходимость добавки карт в приложение. Есть версии под Android и iOS, с первым разобрался без каких то проблем, стал пробовать iOS. Для начала - с библиотеками работа идет через Cocoapods, т.к. это крайне удобный и уже привычный для меня процесс.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!

target 'Application' do

pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField'
pod 'SVGgh'
pod ‘VK-ios-sdk’
pod ‘Kingfisher’
pod ‘Toucan’
pod ‘FBSDKCoreKit’
pod ‘FBSDKLoginKit’
pod ‘FBSDKShareKit’
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'YandexMapKit'

end
```

после чего выполнил pod install. ПРоцесс прошел успешно и я отправился в main.storyboard создавать ViewController. Это тоже не вызвало проблем, взял UIView, растянул его на макет, применил AutoLayout, выбрал класс YMKMapView, любезно предложенный автодополнением и начал делать аутлеты. Здесь и начались проблемы, так как в списке библиотек, доступных для импорта я нашел только MapKit (подозреваю, что тот самый), но добавление его в файл с исходным кодом контроллера не помогло компилятору отпределить YMKMapView, то есть я подключил либо не тот namespace, либо тот, но что то сделал неправильно. Пересмотрел список доступных импортов и убедился что больше добавлять нечего. Кто использовал YMK с swift? Есть ли ьам какие то особенности установки?

UPDATE 1

ознакомился с информацией по следующей ссылке
https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-ios/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-Yandex-Map-Kit-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82

учел все описанные особенности, но результата это не принесло, все равно я вижу сообщение Use undeclared type YMKMapView

UPDATE 2

модуль MapKit похоже относится к фреймворкам iOS, то есть несмотря на то, что я установил pod, xcode не видит его или я не нашел его в списке импортов, следовательно вопрос может свестись к следующей формулировке - как называется модуль, который нужно импортировать для работы YMK?

Comment: чисто для моего спокойствия: вы же workspace запустили, а не проект?

Comment: Да, все правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В bridging header надо добавить

```
#import "YandexMapKit.h"
```

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо.